# Is there any csh alternative for printf %q of bash?

Tags: shell, csh

Bash's build in command `printf` supports the %q format string, which escapes the content of a variable for shell input.

I have tried some options:`:q` only escaped space, and gnu printf does not support `%q`.

Currently, I use below code:

```csh
set valq = `echo $val:q | bash -c 'read q;printf %q "$q"'`
/path/to/executable $valq
```

I do not like csh script having dependency of bash. Is there any csh native solution for this?

Thanks.

---

Here is a test code for illustrating the problem I have met.

wrapper.csh

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set i = 1
set tst1 = ""
set tst2 = ""
while ( $i <= $#argv )
    set arg = "$argv[$i]"
    set tst1 = ($tst1:q $arg:q)
    set arg2 = `echo $arg:q | bash -c 'read q;printf %q "$q"'`
    set tst2 = "$tst2:q $arg2:q"
    @ i = $i + 1
end
echo "====case 1===="
./test.csh $tst1:q
./test.csh $tst1
./test.csh $tst2
echo "====case 2===="
csh -cf "./test.csh $tst1"
csh -cf "./test.csh $tst1:q"
csh -cf "./test.csh $tst2"
```

test.csh

```
#!/bin/csh -f
echo -n "TEST ARG:"
set i = 1
while ($i <= $#argv)
    echo -n "${i}:$argv[$i] "
    @ i = $i + 1
end
echo
```

Test Results 1:
    `>./wrapper.csh "a ()" b c`

```
====case 1====
TEST ARG:1:a () 2:b 3:c
TEST ARG:1:a 2:() 3:b 4:c
TEST ARG:1:a\ 2:\(\) 3:b 4:c
====case 2====
Badly placed ()'s.
Badly placed ()'s.
TEST ARG:1:a () 2:b 3:c
```

Test Results 2:
    `bash>./wrapper.csh "'\"a ()" b c` `csh>./wrapper.csh "'"'"'"a ( ) " b c`

```
====case 1====
TEST ARG:1:'"a () 2:b 3:c
TEST ARG:1:'"a 2:() 3:b 4:c
TEST ARG:1:\'\"a\ 2:\(\) 3:b 4:c
====case 2====
Unmatched '.
Unmatched '.
TEST ARG:1:'"a () 2:b 3:c
```

---

Summary for the test:

- If commands is directly called inside csh, then `$val:q` is the proper usage.
- If commands is passed by arguments, then `printf %q` is the proper usage.

Comment: I cannot help but note that `Badly placed ()'s` is one of the many reasons to avoid `csh` altogether.

Comment: Your shebangs are incorrect throughout.  You need an exclamation mark in `#!/bin/csh -f` in order for the shebang to be recognized.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks, I have fix the typo in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `/path/to/executable "$val"`.

### Update

If variables are expanded within `"` (as in `csh -cf "test.csh $tst1"`) and if special characters and multiple words are to be preserved, the words must indeed be quoted. But the special `printf` of `bash` isn't indispensable for this; we could do it e. g. with:

```
set tst1q=`printf " '%s'" $tst1:q`
csh -cf "test.csh $tst1q"
```

(the normal `printf` without `%q`).

### Update

To allow both `"` and `'`, you can after you initially do

```
    set s='s/[] "$&-*;<>?`|~[]/\\&/g'
```

replace `bash -c 'read q;printf %q "$q"'` with `sed "$s"` in `wrapper.csh`.

The regular expression

```
[] "$&-*;<>?`|~[]
```

is a *bracket expression*, a list of characters enclosed in `[]`. It matches a single character which is to be prepended with a backslash by the replacement `\\&` (the special character `&` refers to the matched character). I didn't include the characters `,` and `^` (they are escaped by `printf %q`, but that's not needed in `csh`), while I included `~` (which isn't escaped by `printf %q`, but needs to be in `csh` - try `wrapper.csh "~"`).

Comment: executable will treat "$val" as one argument. `set val="ab cd"; csh -c 'echo $#argv' "$val"` will return 1. `set val="ab cd"; csh -c 'echo $#argv' ``bash -c "printf %q '$val'"``` will return 2, which is very useful when  implement a wrapper using csh.

Comment: @TerrenceSun: Just `csh -c 'echo $#argv' $val` also outputs `2`. Can you give an example where `%q` is really needed?

Comment: Yes, this will work for string that does not contain `'`. Please test it with input `wrapper.csh "it's a " b c`, %q also failed. Any better idea?

Comment: @TerrenceSun: Do you need to allow `"` as well? (If not, we could simply exchange the quotes, i. e. `printf ' "%s"' $tst1:q`.)

Comment: I'm trying to implement a wrapper with csh, so as to improve the usage of a program with very complex arguments. Some of the argument may be string type (e.g. comment), in which case `'` and `"` maybe appeared.  Changing quotes according to the content is not enough, when they are both appeared. So the first wanted option is some build in quotation.

Comment: I update wrapper again, now `%q` works with `'` and `"`.

Comment: This is a sed's version of bash's quote, am I right? Is ] "$&-*;<>?`|~[  the full set of special char that need to be quoted? Also, would you please explain a little more about the regexp used here?

Comment: @TerrenceSun: Yes, you're right. The given set is not quite the full set of special characters that would need to be quoted. ASCII control characters are not included here. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: I have check the source code of bash, in `lib/sh/quote.c`, we can get a full list of quoted char: `TAB, LF, SPACE, !, DQUOTE, DOL, AMP, SQUOTE, LPAR, RPAR, STAR, COMMA, SEMI, LESSTHAN, GREATERTHAN, QUEST, LBRACK, BS, RBRACK, CARAT,  BACKQ LBRACE, BAR, RBRACE`